# DELL, Windows 10

Tags: google-chrome

I have a Chrome icon on my taskbar and desktop. If I left-click it, it glows as if to open, but then the glowing goes away and nothing happens. If I right-click it, then I can successfully open Chrome by clicking 'New window' or 'New incognito window' under 'Tasks'. Someone please advise how can I fix this so that I can open the google chrome from task bar/desktop by left clicking. It was working well with windows 10 and this problem happened two days ago.

Comment: Have you tried any research on your own to resolve this ?

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem also, A re-install of Chrome Fixed it for me, Strange issue I have no idea what caused it.

Answer (score 0):

You may have an instance of Chrome already running in the background on your machine, so the left-click doesn't open a window.

- Take a look at **Task Manager** (right-click the taskbar and select `Task Manager` or `Start -> Run -> taskmgr`) for any `chrome.exe` processes and end/kill them.
- You can also view/close them via **PowerShell** by issuing the `get-process chrome` & `stop-process chrome -Force` commands.

When you are certain there are no Chrome processes running, try opening Chrome from your taskbar shortcut as you normally would.

If that doesn't work, try rebooting your machine to see if the issue still exists.

If the reboot doesn't fix it, I would suggest an uninstalling and  reinstall of Chrome, as [Harvey](https://superuser.com/users/489571/harvey) already mentioned.